# Flattening XML structure in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataItems>
    <DataItem>
        <ID>ID1</ID>
        <Metric1>Metric11Value</Metric1>
        <Metric2>Metric12Value</Metric2>
        <OptionalParameters>
           <OptionalParameter>
              <ParameterName>ParamName1</ParameterName>
              <ParameterValue>ParamValue1</ParameterValue>
              <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits1</ParameterUnits>
           <OptionalParamter> 
           <OptionalParameter>
              <ParameterName>ParamName2</ParameterName>
              <ParameterValue>ParamValue2</ParameterValue>
              <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits2</ParameterUnits>
           <OptionalParamter>
           <OptionalParameter>
              <ParameterName>ParamName3</ParameterName>
              <ParameterValue>ParamValue3</ParameterValue>
              <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits3</ParameterUnits>
           <OptionalParamter>
        </OptionalParamters>
    <DataItem>
        <ID>ID2</ID>
        <Metric1>Metric21Value</Metric1>
        <Metric2>Metric22Value</Metric2>
        <OptionalParameters>
           <OptionalParameter>
              <ParameterName>ParamName1</ParameterName>
              <ParameterValue>ParamValue1</ParameterValue>
              <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits1</ParameterUnits>
           <OptionalParamter> 
           <OptionalParameter>
              <ParameterName>ParamName2</ParameterName>
              <ParameterValue>ParamValue2</ParameterValue>
              <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits2</ParameterUnits>
           <OptionalParamter>
           <OptionalParameter>
              <ParameterName>ParamName3</ParameterName>
              <ParameterValue>ParamValue3</ParameterValue>
              <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits3</ParameterUnits>
           <OptionalParamter>
        </OptionalParamters>
    <DataItem>
</DataItems>
```

I would like to flatten it in a fashion that will give me a table row like

```
(ID, Metric1, Metric2, ParamName, ParamValue, ParamUnits)
```

The problem is that I don't know how do peform the dynamic filtering I need in order to eliminate the invalid rows that result during the inner join or cross apply. So what I have essentially a total of (Number of Data Items)^2 of rows with all the permutations of parameters names, values, and units. I want to know how to filter out the invalid rows.

Comment: Are you saying that the *cartesian product* occurs when you create the XML document, or when you flatten the XML document?  Your question doesn't seem to relate to the XML document provided and the statement `I would like to flatten it in a fashion that will give me a table row like...`.

Comment: I likely was not clear. Flattening is essentially a cartesian product from which the invalid combinations are filtered out. I attempted to accomplish this with an inner join and a cross apply but didn't quite understand how i could filter out the rows given that i was working with xml. I have since figured that out however the method in your answer seems a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your XML is messed up.  You have a bunch of **open** XML elements that do not have matching **close** elements.  If you fix that, then it is easy to get the flattened output you want:

```
declare @idoc int, @xml varchar(max) = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataItems>
  <DataItem>
    <ID>ID1</ID>
    <Metric1>Metric11Value</Metric1>
    <Metric2>Metric12Value</Metric2>
    <OptionalParameters>
      <OptionalParameter>
        <ParameterName>ParamName1</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>ParamValue1</ParameterValue>
        <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits1</ParameterUnits>
      </OptionalParameter>
    </OptionalParameters>
    <OptionalParameters>
      <OptionalParameter>
        <ParameterName>ParamName2</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>ParamValue2</ParameterValue>
        <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits2</ParameterUnits>
      </OptionalParameter>
    </OptionalParameters>
    <OptionalParameters>
      <OptionalParameter>
        <ParameterName>ParamName3</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>ParamValue3</ParameterValue>
        <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits3</ParameterUnits>
      </OptionalParameter>
    </OptionalParameters>
  </DataItem>
  <DataItem>
    <ID>ID2</ID>
    <Metric1>Metric21Value</Metric1>
    <Metric2>Metric22Value</Metric2>
    <OptionalParameters>
      <OptionalParameter>
        <ParameterName>ParamName1</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>ParamValue1</ParameterValue>
        <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits1</ParameterUnits>
      </OptionalParameter>
    </OptionalParameters>
    <OptionalParameters>
      <OptionalParameter>
        <ParameterName>ParamName2</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>ParamValue2</ParameterValue>
        <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits2</ParameterUnits>
      </OptionalParameter>
    </OptionalParameters>
    <OptionalParameters>
      <OptionalParameter>
        <ParameterName>ParamName3</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>ParamValue3</ParameterValue>
        <ParameterUnits>ParamUnits3</ParameterUnits>
      </OptionalParameter>
    </OptionalParameters>
  </DataItem>
</DataItems>'

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @xml

select *
from   openxml(@idoc, '/DataItems/DataItem/OptionalParameters/OptionalParameter', 1)
with   (
          ID varchar(5) '../../ID', 
          Metric1 varchar(18) '../../Metric1', 
          Metric2 varchar(20) '../../Metric2', 
          ParamName varchar(20) 'ParameterName', 
          ParameterValue varchar(20) 'ParameterValue',
          ParameterUnits varchar(20) 'ParameterUnits'
        )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
go
```

Which returns this:

```
ID    Metric1            Metric2              ParamName            ParameterValue       ParameterUnits
----- ------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
ID1   Metric11Value      Metric12Value        ParamName1           ParamValue1          ParamUnits1
ID1   Metric11Value      Metric12Value        ParamName2           ParamValue2          ParamUnits2
ID1   Metric11Value      Metric12Value        ParamName3           ParamValue3          ParamUnits3
ID2   Metric21Value      Metric22Value        ParamName1           ParamValue1          ParamUnits1
ID2   Metric21Value      Metric22Value        ParamName2           ParamValue2          ParamUnits2
ID2   Metric21Value      Metric22Value        ParamName3           ParamValue3          ParamUnits3
```